# Accessing a service before BuildServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

Im failing to build the following service, since configStoreService need to be injected to the AddInMemoryConfiguration, ConfigurationBuilder. So, is there a way to retrieve configStoreService and use it before building the service provider.

```
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            var configStoreService = services.AddSingleton<ConfigurationStore>();
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddInMemoryConfiguration(configStoreService)
               .Build();
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<Temp>(configuration.GetSection(typeof(Temp).Name));
            services.RegisterOptionsType<Temp>(configuration);
            _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Foreword:**

This seems a problematic request. You need configuration to configure services, but you need to configure services to get configuration. A chicken and egg problem.

**What to do:**

Create an instance of configuration use it to configure your services and also add it to your service collection

```
var configStoreService = new ConfigurationStore(location, sku);
services.AddSingleton(configStoreService);
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .AddInMemoryConfiguration(configStoreService)
           .Build();
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<Temp>(configuration.GetSection(typeof(Temp).Name));
services.RegisterOptionsType<Temp>(configuration);
_serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

**FYI:**

I also have to add you can't get anything from a `IServiceCollection`. You can get things from `IServiceProvider`which, you get AFTER registration is done and `BuildServiceProvider` called. So before that you can't access items in the collection.